# Compile error in Arduino IDE using Mozzi library

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm using the Mozzi lib (http://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/) as part of a tutorial (http://www.echanter.com/home/howto-build#TOC-Arduino-IDE). I included the Mozzi in Arduino Studio and followed minor configs in the tutorial. I've looked around the lines that are reported, but I'm stumped. Compile error is:

```
Mozzi/mozzi_fixmath.cpp.o: In function isqrt16(unsigned int)': /home/temp/sketchbook/libraries/Mozzi/mozzi_fixmath.cpp:156: multiple definition of isqrt32(unsigned long)'
echanter.cpp.o:/home/temp/sketchbook/libraries/Mozzi/Sample.h:61: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root dir are two files with isqrt16(unsigned int) defined: mozzi_fixmath.cpp and mozzi_fixmath.h. I commented out the definition in the cpp file and it compiled.